# How do I start a transaction in sqlalchemy without regard to whether it is nested or not?

Tags: sqlalchemy

## Context

I would like to make use of nested transactions using SQLAlchemy (in postgres), but I want to write an independent function that doesn't care if the session already has a transaction or not -- it can start a nested transaction or outer transaction appropriately.

## Question

What is the most elegant syntax to begin a transaction, which will be either an outer or nested transaction, as appropriate?

So far the best I have seen is:
`session.begin(nested=session.is_active)`

Is there something better than this?

## Discussion

I am using postgres, which does not natively support nested transactions, so nested transactions are implemented using the SAVEPOINT command.

Specifically, what the above code does (against postgres, at least) is:
* If there is no transaction in progress, start a (non-nested) transaction (BEGIN)
* If there is already a transaction in progress, begin a nested transaction (SAVEPOINT)

Is there something better than this? Ideally I'd like to just call `session.begin()` and have it internally work out if it needs to be an outer transaction (BEGIN) or a nested transaction (SAVEPOINT) without me having to be explicit about it.

## Motivation

I would like to write a function `f(session)` which takes a SQLAlchemy session and makes some changes within a transaction. Also, I want the ability to rollback the changes that `f()` has made (and *only* the changes that `f()` has made).

If the calling code has begun a transaction, and made changes, then I don't want a rollback within `f()` to discard changes that were made by the calling code.